# Sensor value for each four type orientation

Tags: android

I am using OrientationEventListener() for detecting orientation change but it gives continuous values.I want only four values for each orientation i.e PORTRAIT,REVERSE_PORTRAIT,LANDSCAPE AND REVERSE_LANDSCAPE MODE.what should i do to get values only if orientation changes.My problem is i want to detect orientation  when device quickly turns from LANDSCAPE MODE to REVERSE LANDSCAPE MODE.I want to call currentScreenOrientation() function only once when orientation changes but now it is calling it for every value between 0 to 359.

```
        mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
                currentScreenOrientation();
            }
        };

        if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            mOrientationEventListener.enable();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save the orientation of the device when app started

```
mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
mCurrentOrientation = mDisplay.getRotation(); // return values are 0, 90, ...
```

And in  `onOrientationChanged` checked if orientation has changed

```
@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)
{

      if (mDisplay.getRotation() != mCurrentOrientation)
      {
          mCurrentOrientation = mDisplay.getRotation();
          currentScreenOrientation();
      }

 }
```